# Problem with hidden Excel add-in

Tags: microsoft-excel

My Excel 2010 VBA editor is very strange. Whenever I type a blank it will be deleted. Found some other users with the same problem [e.g. here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/vba-editor-window-bug-spacebar-immediately-backspace-t1640586.html).

The solution talks about forms running but I don't have any forms active. I disabled all add-ins in the options, restarted excel with a fresh empty workbook but the problem stays.

The strange thing is that problem disappears if I start excel in `safe mode` (/s startup switch).

My conclusion is that there must be some hidden add-on which is causing the problem. Where can I look for these hidden add-ons? registry, disk folders etc.

I have ran a complete virus/malware scan

Comment: Have you checked Com Addins in Excel as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Did a clean uninstall of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218/) and reinstalled and everything works fine again.